# Real-time video stream with QtQuick

Tags: video-streaming, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick

I'd like to stream video in as close to real-time as possible in my QML/QtQuick applications.

I've tested:

```
import QtMultimedia 5.0
Video { source : "http://mysource" }
```

with vlc as server (0ms buffer) and stream-m, both with delays up to 30 seconds. So my question is twofold:

- What media streaming formats does QtQuick support?
- What type of media should I use to stream; say for example my webcam, as close to real-time as possible?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK answers completely depend on which [Multimedia Backend](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt_Multimedia_Backends) has been used (for instance `GStreamer`, `VLC`). So firstly you should know which backend you uses, secondly you should review documentation for the concrete multimedia backend, to find answers on your questions